# Use Fn::ImportValue to import a list of all subnets exported from another stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc, subnet

I currently have two stacks, where stack A is generated by CDK and has the following configured output:

```
"ExporttestNetworkStackuseast1AllPrivateSubnets": {
   "Value": "test-NetworkStack-us-east-1:PrivateSubnet1,test-NetworkStack-us-east-1:PrivateSubnet2,test-NetworkStack-us-east-1:PrivateSubnet3,test-NetworkStack-us-east-1:PrivateSubnet4,test-NetworkStack-us-east-1:PrivateSubnet5,test-NetworkStack-us-east-1:PrivateSubnet6",
   "Export": {
    "Name": "test-NetworkStack-us-east-1:AllPrivateSubnets"
   }
  },
```

Where each comma separated entry is the export name for that subnet resource in the same stack. I am trying to pass all of these subnets into Stack B without hardcoding every single subnet and availabilityzone, specifically in `"VPCZoneIdentifier"` under the creation of Auto scaling groups.

For stack B I can only work in Cloudformation template (no CDK), and I'm having trouble writing logic that can automatically import the resource for all of those subnets. Here is something that I've tried that clearly does not work:

```
"VPCZoneIdentifier" : [
                    { "Fn::ImportValue" : {
                        "Fn::Split" : [ "," , 
                            { "Fn::ImportValue" : { "Fn::Sub" :  "${DeploymentType}-NetworkStack-${AWS::Region}:AllPrivateSubnets" }}
                        ]}
                    }
                ],
```

Just to reiterate my goal, I am trying to find a scale-able solution to import all private subnets generated by cdk, instead of having to manually update every subnet for every availability zone that I am trying to leverage (which is all of them). My old, manual way of doing it was:

```
"VPCZoneIdentifier" : [
                    { "Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${DeploymentType}-NetworkStack-${AWS::Region}:PrivateSubnet1"} },
                    { "Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${DeploymentType}-NetworkStack-${AWS::Region}:PrivateSubnet2"} }
                ],
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with your current attempts? Any errors?

Comment: Yes, Importvalue has to be a string, not a list of strings (since Fn::Split returns list of strings)

Comment: Well then you already know the answer - its not possible to import a list.